# gradle compileJava error java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, gradle, java-8

I am trying run gradle project, every task which included javaCompile fails.
I getting

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
.........
```

Run on Ubuntu 17.04, oracle java 1.8.0_144-b01,
gradle -v

```
Gradle 4.0.2
Build time:   2017-07-26 15:04:56 UTC
Revision:     108c593aa7b43852f39045337ee84ee1d87c87fd
Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:           Linux 4.10.0-30-generic amd64
```

I trying several versions of gradle, jdk9, jvmargs like

```
compileJava {
options.fork = true
options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += ["-Xms2048m", "-Xmx4096m","-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m", "-XX:+UseCompressedOops"]}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting with one of the known issue in java [JDK-8077306](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8077306) 
This has been already fixed in jdk9. Upgrading to jdk9 could resolve this issue.

As this is not backported to 8, so you cannot make any workaround in 8.

Comment: This solved my problem as I use sdkman for managing versions of my tools. My Android Studio was pointing to `j9-adpt` instead of the `hs-adpt` versions of the JDK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just had the same problem after updating to gradle 5.4 -> 6.5 on android studio 4.13 (ubuntu)  Upgrade from java 1.8 to 1.11 fixed the problem.  Thanks!